# Gradle in IntelliJ cannot find Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, spring-jdbc

I created spring rest API in *IntelliJ IDEA* using *Gradle*. When I am using the *JDBCTemplate* it is not imported in the project, and I get the following message:

```
package org.springframework.jdbc.core does not exist import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate; in gradle intellij
```

Even though this jar file is showing in the external libraries.

Comment: Does the package appear under External Libraris in Project window? If not, try to reimport gradle project (left side, gradle window).

Comment: Where do you get the error message? In IntelliJ itself, or when running the project directly? Have you tried running it with gradle in the terminal? If not, could you please try that, to pin down if it's a gradle setup thing, or IntelliJ. Also, could you please share your `build.gradle`? That might also help us to help you :) Thanks